# Automatically execute a command in PuTTY opened from WinSCP

Tags: putty, login, winscp

I am using WinSCP with PuTTY and I have setup an auto login to PuTTY from WinSCP. I have a bat file that opens the WinSCP and several connections to remote machines and once the WinSCP connects it also automatically opens the PuTTY.

What I want is to send command `top` to the PuTTY after login. Is there any way to do it ?

I am monitoring several Linux servers. I want that after the PC starts up, it automatically opens PuTTY console with and send a `top` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [WinSCP preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_preferences) go to the [*Integration > Applications* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_integration_app).

There specify the following command in the [*PuTTY/Terminal client path* box](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_integration_app#client_path):

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\PuTTY\putty.exe" -t -m "%TEMP%\putty.txt" !`cmd.exe /c echo top > "%TEMP%\putty.txt"`
```

---

It follows the same approach as suggested for [opening PuTTY in the same directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#putty_startup_directory) in WinSCP documentation. Just instead of the `cd` command, use the `top`. For details see the link.

Comment: Well, but there is one problem, later if I want to start up another season of putty for something different than watching top I cannot leave the top because once I do ctrl+c the session and entire putty windows is closed.

Comment: Replace the `top` with `top ; /bin/bash` to start a bash shell after you terminate the `top`.